# SQL Server unique index allowing duplicates

Tags: sql-server, unique-index

I am using SQL Server 2008, had a table with an id (numeric) column as the primary key.  Also had a unique index on three varchar columns. I was able to add a row with the exact same set of the three columns.  I verified it with a simple query on the values and 2 rows were returned.

I edited the index and added the id column.  When I tried to edit it again and remove the id column it complained that there were duplicate rows, it deleted the index but couldn't create it.

I then clean the database of the duplicated, recreated the index with the same 3 varchars as unique and nonclustered and now it works properly, not allowing duplicates.

Does anyone know why the uniqueness of this index was ignored?

Comment: The index was not disabled, and the values were exactly the same: atsolberg.com/dupPaos.JPG Here's a pic showing the properties of the index and the query + results of two rows returned. I also added len(*)'s in the select to ensure the varchars values were the same length. Also these rows are not old rows add before the index existed, they were just added.

Answer (score 5):

The index could had been disabled (see [Disabling Indexes](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177406.aspx)), your 'duplicate' values may had been different (trailing spaces for example), or your test may be incorrect.

For sure you did not insert a duplicate in a enforced unique index.

Comment: The index was not disabled, and the values were exactly the same: http://atsolberg.com/dupPaos.JPG Here's a pic showing the properties of the index and the query + results of two rows returned.  I also added len(***)'s in the select to ensure the varchars values were the same length. 

Also these rows are not old rows add before the index existed, they were just added.

Comment: Repro script and I'll believe you.

Comment: SI also important to look at the SET ANSI PADDING setting and the collation under which the SELECT WHERE clause matches the value.

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*), PAOClass, Category, PAOName FROM YukonPAOObject HAVING COUNT(*)>1 GROUP BY PAOClass, Catgory, PAOName`. Does this return any rows?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a pro on this subject, but the 'is unique'-setting of the index probably refers to the way the index is build/stored, not that it is a constraint. This probably also means the performance of the index is sub-optimal.
When creating the index, the DBMS might check this.